# Capybara Poltergeist ActionCable testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, poltergeist, actioncable

I wrote an application (**with rails 5.0.0beta3**) which has several live updates using `ActionCable`.
So I wanted to test what I wrote. I added [poltergeist](https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist) to my Gemfile and bundled it and ran an example.
Javascript is correctly executed.

But when sprocket tries to add action_cable it fails:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'this.events[eventName].bind(this)')
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'this.events[eventName].bind(this)')
    at http://127.0.0.1:63829/assets/application-2d6ae1aa6efc25d4e4902c5f2d384b5473eb4bdcc9489a9857608e6fe9952eb5.js:12789
...
```

I think this comes from [this line right here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/9c2945f4cc1017fc9424f2e425e4820da1ef33b0/actioncable/app/assets/javascripts/action_cable/connection.coffee#L74)

If this is not the way to test action cable, how should I do that?

Comment: siegy, could you point out a code snippet/repo where you successfully tested actioncable with rspec/capybara?

Comment: @SzilardMagyar Will do that later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're most likely using an old version of phantomjs which doesn't have support for `bind`. Upgrade to phantomjs 2.1.1+

Comment: Thanks so much!
Why isn't 2.1.1 on homebrew available?

Comment: @RaVeN. It should be - https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/fb81645562f7e495a49561065912788af2d1f14f/Formula/phantomjs.rb - maybe your homebrew needs updating

Comment: Did you get your tests running with poltergeist? Now it just says `[ActionCable] WebSocket onerror event` if I enable debugging in action cable.. :(

Comment: I have tests using all different drivers, off the top of my head I'm not sure if any of my actioncable tests are using poltergeist   You do need to use puma with Capybara instead of the default webrick.  Use Capybara 2.7.0+ and specify `Capybara.server = :puma`

Comment: If you're not using poltergeist what else do you use?
I ran into the next problem.. the tests get stucked sometimes. (ruby process stuck)

Comment: Are you using 5.0.0beta3 or are you on master branch of rails?  If beta3 you might be hitting https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/24491 , if master  https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/24094 or https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/24028